# Jquery Selectors: how to select div in nested divs

Tags: jquery

```
<div id ="parent"> 

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>

</div>
```

how to select div with text "2" in the div with id=parent.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

The solutions by [Adil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313023/1456376) and [kayen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313012/1456376) are fine but might [fail on an example like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gqXdz/):

```
<div>12</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

This is a solution that will always find the exact match:

```
var div = $('#parent div').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === '2'; });
```

If the values can have whitespaces, for example like this:

```
<div>
    2
</div>
```

you need to trim the string before the comparison:

```
$('#parent div').filter(function() { return $.trim($(this).text()) === '2'; });
```

**Demo**

Without `.trim()`: [Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/GULK9/)

With `.trim()`: [Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/kaJd6/)

Comment: Clearly a better solution.  I would also use `$.trim` if whitespace is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('#parent').find('div:contains("2")')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select div by `:contains`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JQpGk/2/)**

```
$('#parent div:contains("2")')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQpGk/5/)

```
$('div div:contains("2")')
```